# Issues in Many to Many Model in Operating System

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, many-to-many, threadpool, one-to-one

I have read the Many to Many Model in Operating System book by "Abraham Silberschatz". In chapter 4 it says that

**"The Solaris operating system supported the many to many model in versions older than Solaris 9. However,
beginning with Solaris 9, this system uses the one-to-one model."**

My Question are given in the following.
May be answer mention in book and I can't understand it, and I search on internet also but can't find a useful information why shift happen?

1. **what are the issues with many to many model?**
2. **Why shift occur from many to many model to one to one model?**

Answer (score 2):

I've only worked on systems that implement what some call the one-to-one model. This classification of one-to-one/many-to-many/and many-to-one IMHO is misleading.

The suggestion here is that, in the "one-to-one model," each thread really creates two threads: A kernel mode thread and a user mode thread. In reality, all that is needed a single thread that can operate in both user and kernel modes (i.e., a kernel mode stack).

The advantage a thread that can operate in both kernel and user mode (an possibly other modes as well, aka one-to-one model) is that the threads can operate completely independently and is likely simpler to implement. Each thread can enter kernel mode (e.g. perform I/O) without blocking any other thread. The alleged downside is that this requires each thread to have its own kernel mode stack.

Again, I have not worked on a many-to-one or many-to-many system but I would suspect that these are not implemented with separate kernel mode threads but rather with kernel mode data structures that are shared by multiple threads.

> what are the issues with many to many model?

The clear downside to many-to-many and many-to-one is that kernel mode becomes a resource whose unavailability can cause one group of threads to block another group of threads.

Let's say you have 3 kernel mode "threads" and 10 user mode threads. If 4 user mode threads try to do I/O at the same time, the 4th thread will block until one of the first three threads complete.

It is also more complicated to implement because you would have to manage the kernel mode "threads" as resources.

> Why shift occur from many to many model to one to one model?

I cannot think of any practicable advantage of one-to-many or many-to-many and can think of many disadvantages (above). That is probably why there was a shift.

That said, IMHO, this is a confusing way to explain threading.